# Removing iceweasel from Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, aptitude, iceweasel

On Debian Wheezy, when trying to remove Iceweasel, aptitude suggests, both when I try it via GUI and via `aptitude remove iceweasel` to also remove the following:

```
1)     gnome                                                                    
2)     gnome-core                                                               
3)     iceweasel-l10n-pt-br                                                     
4)     task-gnome-desktop                                                       
5)     xul-ext-adblock-plus
```

Is it safe to proceed with the removal of this packages? It says only about 500KB of data will be removed, but `gnome` and `gnome-core` seem kind of important.

Answer (score 2):

Then `gnome` and `gnome-core` packages are meta-packages, meaning that they 
exist only to depend on other packages making it easier to install a complete 
set of packages.  Here `iceweasel` is considered to be part of the set and so 
it is included as a dependency.  So removing those packages will not remove 
anything important.

**But**, if those packages are not installed, when you upgrade your system any 
new Gnome components that would have been pulled in by those meta packages will 
not be installed. This still shouldn't cause anything to break since individual 
packages will have dependencies on the packages that they require; but it would 
mean that you would no longer have a complete Gnome environment (minus 
iceweasel).